# How does one calculate Fisher-consistency factor for Rousseeuw and Croux's $S_n$ for empirical distribution?

Tags: median, estimators, consistency, mad

In ["Alternatives to the Median Absolute Deviation" (Rousseeuw and Croux, J. Amer. Statistical Assoc, 88(424), 1993, pp.1273–1283)](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/astro_refs/BetterThanMAD.pdf), the authors  described an estimator of SD better than median absolute deviation (MAD), $S_n$. In equation 2.4, the calculation of Fisher-consistency factor $c$ is described for a model distribution F.

How do I calculate $c$ for an empirical distribution that I do not know what the model distribution F is?

Comment: Without knowing (that is, assuming) the theoretical distribution family I doubt that you can calculate $c$

Answer (score 1):

Calculation of such Fisher-consistency factors is usually done assuming a normal distribution, so you get a method that is more robust than the usual normal-based methods, but still consistent at the normal (family).  Without looking up the referenced paper, I would guess that is what they are doing. One could do that calculation also for other distribution families, and that could indeed be an interesting exercise, to see how much such factors vary among distribution families.

What is indeed quite remarkable about the usual variance estimator (dividing by $n-1$) is that it is not only consistent, but unbiased without assuming some specific distribution. That is quite remarkable, and not to be expected in general for estimators.